# Why do I get an AttributeError when using pandas apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, attributeerror

How should I convert NaN value into categorical value based on condition. I am getting error while trying to convert Nan value.

```
category           gender     sub-category    title

health&beauty      NaN         makeup         lipbalm

health&beauty      women       makeup         lipstick

NaN                NaN         NaN            lipgloss
```

My DataFrame looks like this. And my function to convert NaN values in gender to categorical value looks like

```
def impute_gender(cols):
    category=cols[0]
    sub_category=cols[2]
    gender=cols[1]
    title=cols[3]
    if title.str.contains('Lip') and gender.isnull==True:
        return 'women'
df[['category','gender','sub_category','title']].apply(impute_gender,axis=1)
```

If I run the code I am getting error

```
----> 7     if title.str.contains('Lip') and gender.isnull()==True:
      8         print(gender)
      9 

AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index category')
```

Complete Dataset -[https://github.com/lakshmipriya04/py-sample](https://github.com/lakshmipriya04/py-sample/blob/master/intern-training-samples.csv)

Comment: What do you think `title.str` is?

Comment: Isn't `isnull` a function that takes an array? [The docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html). I'm not sure `gender.isnull==True` makes sense,

Comment: title is pandas Series. I am looking for Lip in that column

Comment: @LPR btw , if you like other answers , you can upvote :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some things to note here -

1. If you're using only two columns, calling `apply` over 4 columns is wasteful
2. Calling `apply` is wasteful and inefficient, because it is slow, uses a lot of memory, and offers no vectorisation benefits to you
3. In apply, you're dealing with scalars, so you do not use the `.str` accessor as you would a `pd.Series` object. `title.contains` would be enough. Or more pythonically, `"lip" in title`.
4. `gender.isnull` sounds completely wrong to the interpreter because `gender` is a scalar, it has no `isnull` attribute

---

**Option 1**
`np.where`

```
m = df.gender.isnull() & df.title.str.contains('lip')
df['gender'] = np.where(m, 'women', df.gender)

df
        category gender sub-category     title
0  health&beauty  women       makeup   lipbalm
1  health&beauty  women       makeup  lipstick
2            NaN  women          NaN  lipgloss
```

Which is not only fast, but simpler as well. If you're worried about case sensitivity, you can make your `contains` check case insensitive -

```
m = df.gender.isnull() & df.title.str.contains('lip', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

---

**Option 2**
Another alternative is using `pd.Series.mask`/`pd.Series.where` -

```
df['gender'] = df.gender.mask(m, 'women')
```

Or,

```
df['gender'] = df.gender.where(~m, 'women')
```

<!- ->

```
df
        category gender sub-category     title
0  health&beauty  women       makeup   lipbalm
1  health&beauty  women       makeup  lipstick
2            NaN  women          NaN  lipgloss
```

The `mask` implicitly applies the new value to the column based on the mask provided.

Answer (score 7):

Or simply use loc as an option 3 to @COLDSPEED's answer

```
cond = (df['gender'].isnull()) & (df['title'].str.contains('lip'))
df.loc[cond, 'gender'] = 'women'


    category        gender  sub-category    title
0   health&beauty   women   makeup          lipbalm
1   health&beauty   women   makeup          lipstick
2   NaN             women       NaN         lipgloss
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.When should I use apply function? And why do I get attribute error

Comment: @LPR who are you speaking to? I've addressed your problems in my answer. Also, as for when to use apply, the answer would be, when you can't use anything else.

Answer (score 3):

If we are due with NaN values , `fillna` can be one of the method:-)

```
df.gender=df.gender.fillna(df.title.str.contains('lip').replace(True,'women'))
df
Out[63]: 
        category gender sub-category     title
0  health&beauty  women       makeup   lipbalm
1  health&beauty  women       makeup  lipstick
2            NaN  women          NaN  lipgloss
```

Comment: I see you went out of the box to get this one. Nice.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ aha, It is hard to think outside the box : -)

Comment: @Wen, Happy New Year. I answered and went back to enjoying the last day of holiday so missed the message :)